# Camunda with junit5

Tags: junit, camunda, camunda-modeler

I am trying to extend test case for camunda and JUnit5.
I am getting the following error - Illegal call of execute(job = 'null') - must not be null!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal call of execute(job = 'null') - must not be null!

```
@ExtendWith(ProcessEngineExtension.class)
public class SimpleTestCase {

@Deployment(resources = {"testProcess.bpmn"})
@Test
public void shouldExecuteProcess() {

    // Given we create a new process instance
    ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService().startProcessInstanceByKey("testProcess");
    // Then it should be active
    assertThat(processInstance).isActive();
    // And it should be the only instance
    assertThat(processInstanceQuery().count()).isEqualTo(1);
    // And there should exist just a single task within that process instance
    assertThat(task(processInstance)).isNotNull();

    ProcessEngineTests.execute(ProcessEngineTests.job());

   BpmnAwareTests.execute(BpmnAwareTests.job());
    // When we complete that task
    complete(task(processInstance));
    // Then the process instance should be ended
    assertThat(processInstance).isEnded();
    //then
    //Checking the run queue
    assertThat(processInstance).hasPassedInOrder(new String[] { "UserTask_1","UserTask_2"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     ProcessInstance processInstance = 
     runtimeService().startProcessInstanceByKey("testProcess");
    // Then it should be active
    assertThat(processInstance).isActive();
    // And it should be the only instance
    assertThat(processInstanceQuery().count()).isEqualTo(1);
    // And there should exist just a single task within that process instance
    assertThat(task(processInstance)).isNotNull();

    assertThat(processInstance).isWaitingAt("UserTask_1");
    // When we complete that task
    complete(task(processInstance));
    assertThat(processInstance).isWaitingAt("UserTask_2");
    complete(task(processInstance));
    // Then the process instance should be ended
    assertThat(processInstance).isEnded();
    assertThat(processInstance).hasPassedInOrder("UserTask_1","UserTask_2");
```